# how to implement search functionality for different listviews in view pager and segmented contoller

Tags: android, listview, tabs, android-actionbar

I am using action bar ,view pager and segmented controller.main screen contains actionbar with search and below action bar there is one view pager which contains 3 tabs ,each tab contains 6 segment controller tabs and each segmentd contrller tab contains one custom listview ,here is screen [Scrren detials](http://screencast.com/t/AD87KCpOW7tt)
each tab contains custom listview .here i want to implement search functionality like facebook. means if user click on action bar search button one new search screen should display then if user enters search keyword it should display search results from highlighted tab data

Answer (score 1):

get the tab position using the method ontab listener based on the tab position we can do it easily

TO GET TAB POSITION

```
    public void onTabSelected(final Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            tabposition = tab.getPosition();

                        }
```

USE TAB POSITION LIKE THIS
searchview.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


 if(tabposition==0)
     {          
     //Write tab0 search here               
 }
     if(tabposition==1)
{          
//Write tab1 search here                
}

if(tabposition==2)
{          
//Write tab2 search here                
  }
return TRUE;
}
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

repeat the same thinng like verifying based on positions
return true;
        }
    });
```

If u have still doubts feel free to contact me